# Spring bean profile reference

Tags: spring, profiling

I started using bean profile for conditional bean creation, but When i use the profiled bean outside of profile with `ref` I get exception `nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'pb' is defined`

```
<bean id="q" class="com.Q">     //spring can not create this bean since it depends on `pb` bean which is profiled. 
  <property name="p" ref="pb"/>
</bean>    

    <beans profile="a">
        <bean id="pb" class="com.T"/>
    </beans> 

    <beans profile="b">
        <bean id="pb" class="com.T"/>
    </beans>
```

How can I achieve this? I am sure `a` profile is on:

```
System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.DEFAULT_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "a");
System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "a");
```

Comment: You may want to check what is the value of those properties at runtime -- as they are system properties, they probably aren't being really written by your `setProperty` calls.

Comment: Where are you setting these system properties? Are you implementing web-application or stand-alone application?

Comment: Never mind it was my mistake, I was setting active profile wrongly, thanks for the answer.